# What's the maximum amount of transactions returned by the get_transfer RPC method?

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc

I'm using the [get_transfer](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/developer-guides/wallet-rpc.html#get_transfers) RPC method.

I'd like to know what the maximum amount of transactions this API can return? Can I filter it using timestamp or pagination instead of block height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation you linked to, you can filter by `min_height/max_height` and `account_index/subaddr_indices`, not timestamp. As Monero blocks are mined roughly every 2 minutes, you can use heights as an approximation of time.

There is no restriction imposed as to the amount of transactions returned other than by the filter options.